# Format XML file in java

Tags: java, xml, dom

I already created an xml, and i was obliged to modify it using `PrintWriter` Class. (copying line by line the xml file and modify what i need) but i lost my indentation. 
i tried this :

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(
                    "notes.xml"))));

                Transformer xformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
                xformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
                xformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
                xformer.setOutputProperty("b;http://xml.apache.org/xsltd;indent-amount", "4");
                //xformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
                Source source = new DOMSource(document);
                Result result = new StreamResult(new File("notes.xml"));
                xformer.transform(source, result);
```

but this isn't working : having an exception in the third line :

```
[Fatal Error] :3:6537: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 3; columnNumber: 6537; XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:257)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:347)
```

> **So, Is there a way to format an already created XML file in java ?**

Comment: *"having an exception in the third line"* which would be what?

Comment: i'll add it to the question

Comment: @MadProgrammer Done! (and i'm sure the xml is in good shape)

Comment: Your XML is formatted badly. Maybe you should reconsider using `PrintWriter` to write it and instead use a `Document`.  You might want to post the XML as well

Comment: I would create an XSD file, generate the classes with XJC and modify the XML that way... a lot easier and less prone to errors and it has the option to output the XML in pretty format.

Comment: Actually you would need to create two XSD files (original and target). But it allows you to validate the original XML. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/xjc.html

Comment: Underscore-java library has static method U.formatXml(xmlstring).